# How to display icon in QMessageBox?

Tags: qt, icons, about-box, qmessagebox

I have an about box that I'm trying to display an icon inside.

Here is my code:

```
QMessageBox about_box(this);

about_box.setText("...");
about_box.setIconPixmap(QPixmap("qrc:/images/logo.png"));
about_box.setParent(this);

about_box.exec();
```

Here is my resource file:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/images">
        <file>logo.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need the `qrc` prefix:

```
about_box.setIconPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/logo.png"));
```

Comment: Perfect! I was used to sticking `qrc:/` in front of images in resource files thanks to QWebView :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need [this function](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qmessagebox.html#iconPixmap-prop)

**EDIT**: I didn't see that the OP had already used this.
Are you sure you're running qmake (and thus rcc) when compiling?

Comment: Actually he is already doing that via `setIconPixmap`. This function is a setter to `iconPixmap` property.